# Identify this old movie about a traveller resting in a “magical” inn

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a film years ago. Maybe mid 90s but it looked old at the time so maybe 60s or even 50s. Upon searching for clues... the film sets of The Band Wagon seem quite similar to some of the “magical kingdom” sets in this film. Backdrop art work with stage sets built in front of them.

The time period of the film was hard to pinpoint. It had a “Snow White” feel to it age wise. The man had a cloak and the women wore skirts and braided hair etc...

It was in English but I believe was set somewhere European. Possibly Switzerland (that would match the outfits and building).

The main protagonist was a male traveller (nomad, wanderer) who, exhausted, comes across a sanctuary. It is a house that is full of women. There is a sort of matriarch figure and 10 or more younger women. The style of the house is very much like a log cabin chalet in the alps.

I remember the young women being very flirtatious towards the man. But the older matriarch was wary about him and didn’t want him around.

They offer him food and rest. Actually... I think they were reluctant to provide refuge for him but he was able to convince them by performing tricks for them (I believe he used his invisible cloak to hide in order to perform the tricks).

The man suspects something odd is happening at night because of noises or something. I think maybe he is given a sleeping potion or something for a few nights.

At night the man hides under a blanket that makes him invisible (I think?!?) and sneaks out and follows the women who all disappear down a door and into a magical kingdom type place. IIRC there is dancing and music and stuff.

I think there is a fountain or a pagoda type structure in the magical place too.

I think he gets discovered in the end but I’m not sure.

It’s a live action film. With a similar film look/quality to films like The Sound of Music or Mary Poppins. Sort of Technicolor style film.

Hope someone can recall what it is. I only ever watched this movie once and was about 10 at the time so I’m struggling to remember any fine details but the more I write the more is coming back to me. If I remember any more I’ll edit the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D edited to add a few extra details that I am slowly remembering. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulie_D oh wow. Well I’m glad I added the extra details. Haha! It is almost certainly this... https://youtu.be/XbWJPiVmjx8 but man did I misremember quite a lot of it. At 32:17 you can even see the pagoda that I remembered. Thanks! I just wish it was as good as I remember it.  add it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a version of Grimms [***"The Dancing Princesses"***](http://www.wikizero.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvVGhlX1R3ZWx2ZV9EYW5jaW5nX1ByaW5jZXNzZXM)...

> The twelve princesses, sure that the soldier is asleep, dress themselves in fine dancing gowns and escape from their room by a trap door in the floor. **The soldier, seeing this, dons his magic cloak and follows them.** He steps on the gown of the youngest princess, whose cry of alarm to her sisters is rebuffed by the eldest. The passageway leads them to three groves of trees; the first having leaves of silver, the second of gold, and the third of glittering diamonds. The soldier, wishing for a token, breaks off a twig of each as evidence. They walk on until they come upon a great clear lake. Twelve boats, with twelve princes, appear where the twelve princesses are waiting. Each princess gets into one, and the soldier steps into the same boat as the twelfth and youngest princess. The youngest princess complains that the prince is not rowing fast enough, not knowing the soldier is in the boat. On the other side of the lake stands a castle, into which all **the princesses go and dance the night away.**

... but the only version I can find is a 1978 UK TV movie..and a 1987 episode of [*Fairy Tale Theatre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faerie_Tale_Theatre)...in fact the very last one

[**IMDB Reference**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199214/)

From the OP's answer to a comment it seems to be the latter.

[image]

Comment: RoboCop dancing with princesses...  :)